# Changing Time Format in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.timing = "1:2"; // Ex: "0.3", 10:1", "2:11", "11:41"
```

I want the above `$scope.timing` in 01:02 format.

How can i can achieve this?

Comment: Moment.js is a great library for everything related to time.

Comment: So `1:2` would output as `01:02` and not `01:20`

Comment: How does `0.3` fit in? Seems out of place

Comment: @George yes, i want it has `01:02`, it automatically takes correct timing when digit is above 10 i.e, `11:41`

Comment: @charlietfl its like 00:03 mins

Comment: What do you mean *"it's like"* ? Are you saying input formats are not consistent? `"0.3"` is not the same as `"0:3"`

Comment: why is the timing in that format -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use moment.js, as anshulk commented. this also is an opportunity to use a custom filter in the template

```
<div ng-bind="vm.timing | hhSSFilter"></div>

function hhSSfilter(input) {
  var result = input.split(':').map(d => {
     return d.length < 2 ? '0' + d : d;
  });
  return result.join(':');
}
```

Comment: fails if you use `11:41`

Comment: also not a legitmate angular filter construct